# Which package provides qmake on Fedora?

Tags: fedora, qt, dnf

I'm having trouble determining the Qt package that provides `qmake` on Fedora 31. I already installed `qt5-designer` `qconf` `qt5-devel` `qt5-qtbase` `qt5-qtbase-devel` `qt5-qttools` `qt5-qttools-devel` (and dependencies).

```
$ dnf search qmake
Last metadata expiration check: 5 days...
============================= Name Matched: qmake ==============================
mingw32-qt5-qmake.x86_64 : Qt5 for Windows build environment
mingw64-qt5-qmake.x86_64 : Qt for Windows build environment
============================ Summary Matched: qmake ============================
qconf.x86_64 : Tool for generating configure script for qmake-based projects
```

`qconf.x86_64` was installed but does not provide it.

```
$ dnf provides qmake
Last metadata expiration check: 5 days...
Error: No Matches found
```

Sorry about this lame question. I can usually find the package on my own.

Which package provides qmake on Fedora 31?

---

The following works as expected on Debian and Ubuntu. It fails on Fedora 31.

```sh
qt-ui$ qmake && make -j 5
bash: qmake: command not found...
Similar command is: 'make'
```

And:

```sh
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: Fedora
Description:    Fedora release 31 (Thirty One)
Release:        31
Codename:       ThirtyOne
```

Comment: What does `dnf provides '*/qmake'` show for you?

Answer (score 4):

The easy way to find out is often just to try installing the file you want:

```
sudo dnf install /usr/bin/qmake
```

but in this case that won't work because the literal answer to your question is that nothing does - rather `qmake-qt5` is provided by `qt5-qtbase-devel` and `qmake-qt4` is provided by `qt-devel`.

So rather than running `qtmake` you will need to run one of those, depending on whether you are trying to build for Qt 4 or Qt 5.

Comment: Thanks @Tom. I believe the tool name is `qmake`, not `qtmake`.

Comment: It seems that `qmake` is really installed via `qt-devel`: `rpm -q --whatprovides /usr/lib64/qt4/bin/qmake
qt-devel-4.8.7-45.fc29.x86_64` Note also that you may need to adjust your PATH to find qmake there.

Comment: Changing the PATH so it can find the qmake executable is probably the answer most people are looking for: `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib64/qt5/bin`. IIRC this is necessary on Fedora 36, but not in Fedora 37. In Fedora 36: `$ dnf provides /usr/bin/qmake
qt6-qtbase-devel-6.2.3-2.fc36.i686 : Development files for qt6-qtbase` and `$ dnf provides /usr/lib64/qt5/bin/qmake
qt5-qtbase-devel-5.15.3-1.fc36.x86_64 : Development files for qt5-qtbase`.

Answer (score 2):

Based on an earlier answer: https://superuser.com/a/1510943/631374

On Fedora 34 it is `sudo dnf install qt6-qtbase-devel` for QT6.

Comment: It's awesome, directly installed qmake and qmake6 on my desktop without any issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
qt-ui$ qmake-qt5 && make -j 5
```

Comment: Welcome on the SU! I formatted your answer, but I suggest to explain, why `qmake-qt5` helps while the ordinary `qmake` does not. Copy-paste answers don't look very well.

Answer (score 1):

On Fedora 33 I had to use `sudo dnf install qt5-qtbase-devel` to be able to use `qmake-qt5`.

Answer (score 0):

On Fedora 32, it is `qt-devel` and `qt5-devel` for Qt4 and Qt5, respectively.

Comment: Looks like it calls the binary `qmake-qt5`